# Search API + Facets + Voting API + Fivestar - Cannot sort by rating, value always 0?

Tags: rating, search

I'm trying to build a faceted search for single content type that has user ratings.

What have I done so far is that I have running Solr server with custom index for content type. I have been able to add and index fivestar (Voting API) fields and facets are visible. However whatever are the results of voting it seems that they won't get indexed corrently and always end to be 0, avarage and user's own rating.

Is there any way to make ratings to play nicely with Search API and faceted search?